# Objective C tyring to learn the correct way to pass method parameters to an object and get the correct result

Tags: objective-c

I'm new to objective C and have been trying to teach myself through books and online tutorials.

I'm trying to write a simple class that has one method that puts a name together.  However, when I try to pass values to it, I get a null result.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TSMPerson : NSObject

@property NSString *first;

@property NSString *last;

@property NSString *middle;

@property NSString *fullName;


- (NSString *) stickNamesTogether: (NSString *) first : (NSString *) middle : (NSString *) last;


@end
```

The implementation is:

```
#import "TSMPerson.h"

@implementation TSMPerson

-(NSString *)stickNamesTogether: (NSString *)first : (NSString *) middle : (NSString *) last
{
    self.fullName=[self.first stringByAppendingString:@" "];
    self.fullName=[self.fullName stringByAppendingString:self.middle];
    self.fullName=[self.fullName stringByAppendingString:@" "];
    self.fullName=[self.fullName stringByAppendingString:self.last];
    return self.fullName;
}

@end
```

The problem I'm having is that when I call this method from another class, I get a null result and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong:

```
#import "TSMViewController.h"
#import "TSMPerson.h"


@interface TSMViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *viewText;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *first;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *middle;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *last;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *printName;

@end

@implementation TSMViewController



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (IBAction)printName:(id)sender {

    TSMPerson *person = [[TSMPerson alloc]init];
    person.fullName=[person stickNamesTogether:self.first.text :self.middle.text         :self.last.text];
    self.viewText.text=person.fullName;
    NSLog(@"fullname is %@",person.fullName);

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

When I use this alternate code, it works:

```
 /*
     TSMPerson *person = [[TSMPerson alloc]init];
     person.first=self.first.text;
     person.middle=self.middle.text;
     person.last=self.last.text;

     person.fullName=[person stickNamesTogether:person.first :person.middle :person.last];

     self.viewText.text=person.fullName;
     */
```

but that gives me the extra task of setting the instantiated properties of the person class to the properties in the viewcontroller.  I'm not sure why I can't just pass those property values right into my method and get back the values I want.

I realize this there is probably some basic thing I'm missing, but I can't figure out what it is.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: BTW - this is what `stringWithFormat` is for. You can do: `self.fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", first, middle, last];`. Of course neither approach is doing what it should do and that is to verify that each value is non-empty. No sense in appending the middle name if there isn't one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are using the properties instead of the variables passed in.

You should use `first`, `middle`, `last` instead of `self.first`, `self.middle`, `self.last`.

Your commented out code works because you are setting those properties first.

I think this is what you want.

```
-(NSString *)stickNamesTogether: (NSString *)first : (NSString *) middle : (NSString *) last
{
    self.fullName=[first stringByAppendingString:@" "];
    self.fullName=[self.fullName stringByAppendingString:middle];
    self.fullName=[self.fullName stringByAppendingString:@" "];
    self.fullName=[self.fullName stringByAppendingString:last];
    return self.fullName;
}
```

Unless you want to also set those properties too (which the above method will not do). Since you ARE setting the fullName property (`self.fullName`) and returning that.

In which case you want

```
-(NSString *)stickNamesTogether: (NSString *)first : (NSString *) middle : (NSString *) last
{
    self.first = fist;
    self.middle = middle;
    self.last = last;

    self.fullName=[first stringByAppendingString:@" "];
    self.fullName=[self.fullName stringByAppendingString:middle];
    self.fullName=[self.fullName stringByAppendingString:@" "];
    self.fullName=[self.fullName stringByAppendingString:last];
    return self.fullName;
}
```

You may reduce confusion by using a different name for the passed in variables.

```
-(NSString *)stickNamesTogether: (NSString *)passedFirst : (NSString *) passedMiddle : (NSString *) passedLast
{
    self.first = passedFirst;
    self.middle = passedMiddle;
    self.last = passedLast;

    self.fullName=[passedFirst stringByAppendingString:@" "];
    self.fullName=[self.fullName stringByAppendingString:passedMiddle];
    self.fullName=[self.fullName stringByAppendingString:@" "];
    self.fullName=[self.fullName stringByAppendingString:passedLast];
    return self.fullName;
}
```

One last suggestion not related to your problem.  Typically you would use stringWithFormat instead for somethign like this

```
-(NSString *)stickNamesTogether: (NSString *)passedFirst : (NSString *) passedMiddle : (NSString *) passedLast
{
    self.first = passedFirst;
    self.middle = passedMiddle;
    self.last = passedLast;

    self.fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", passedFirst, passedMiddle, passedLast];
    return self.fullName;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that worked.  Thanks.  So, when I use "self" it identifies the property from the class, if I just use first, it makes it generic so that some other object can pass along those parameters?

Comment: @user3284547 Your name is non-standard for Objective-C. Although it's legal, its customary to have names for each parameter, not just a ":" followed by the parameter name. A better name would be something like -(NSString *)concatenateFirstName:(NSString *)first middleName:(NSString *)middle lastName:(NSString *)last

Comment: Think of properties as a holding bucket that can be accessed and sometimes written by anyone including your class and other classes with references to your object. The passed in parameters are private to just your function and can not be seen or accessed outside of your function except through where they are passed in. Each serves their own purpose. I've simplifed a bit but this known as variable scope, see this article for more details. http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Variable_Scope_and_Storage_Class

Comment: @user3284547 - If this solved your problem please mark it as answered so others know.

Answer (score 0):

When you make this call:

```
self.fullName=[self.first stringByAppendingString:@" "];
```

`self.first` is nil, and when you pass a message to a nil object, you get nil in return.

It goes on from there, repeatedly setting `self.fullName` to nil.

What you should do is set the properties with the local vars that you've passed into the method first.

@ansible has some good suggestions as well.